# MyLinkedList - losing element on first addition

Tags: c#, generics, linked-list

I have a small problem. When I add value to MyLinkedList, first value gets lost.
I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(value);
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = node;
            tail = head;
        }

        tail.Next = node;
        tail = node;
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyLinkedListEnumerator<T>(head);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If I do

```
head = new Node<T>(default);
tail = head;
```

Then it's working as it should, but that is wrong, LinkedList should be empty on init.

```
static void Main()
{
    var ll = new MyLinkedList<int>();
    ll.Add(1);
    ll.Add(2);
    
    foreach (var i in ll)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Output is 2.
not 1 ; 2 as it should be.

Here I'm adding IEnumerable implementation, so everything is clear.

```
public class MyLinkedListEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private Node<T> current;

    public MyLinkedListEnumerator(Node<T> current)
    {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public T Current => current.Value;

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        //if (current == null) return false;
        current = current.Next;
        return (current != null);
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Reset()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when you create `MyLinkedList<T>` and invoke `Add` two times sequentially, the `head` field becomes the second added value?

Comment: No, for instance when I call Add(1); Add(2); It will display just 2 and the 1 dissapears. Jinak přepokládám, že mluvíte česky, kdyby jste si našel chvilku čas a mrkl na to semnou budu moc rád:) Mohl bych Vám poslat celý projekt do mailu.

Comment: *"it will  display just 2 and the 1 disappears"*: please add the code with which you reproduce the issue. So add the code with which you create the list, add the 2 values, and display the list -- so we can see the whole flow.

Comment: Done, everything is very basic, that concerns me even more.

Comment: Your issue appears to be a bug with the enumeration, but the implementation of `GetEnumerator()` is not provided.

Comment: I added the implementation, I was looking at it for a while and still have no clue.